# Mysql using hardcoded data

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, how would I do something like the following for a demo purpose:

```
select * from ('1', '2') # one row, two columns
```

Or:

```
select * from (('row 1', 1), ('row 2', 2)) # two rows, two columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `select` and `union all`:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x, 2 as y) t
```

and:

```
select *
from (select 'row 1' as x, 1 as y union all
      select 'row 2', 2
     ) t;
```

Many databases support the `values()` syntax:

```
select *
from (values (1, 2)) t(x, y);

select *
from (values ('row 1', 1), ('row 2', 2)) t(x, y);
```

MySQL does not (yet) support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a temporary table:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Column1 NVARCHAR(100),
    Column2 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @table (Column1,Column2) VALUES
('row 1','1'),('row 2','2')

SELECT * FROM @table
```

Comment: Although you *can* do this in MySQL, the code looks nothing like this.